# Will feof return true on php://input if client aborts the request?

Tags: php

This is my method of input, $this->stream is a handle to php://input

Its called in chunks, there is a good chance that I'd run out of resources by trying to deal with the entire request at once so no get_file_contents for me. Smaller separate requests would slow down the upload too much. (rather low end server hardware)

```
function read_bstring($len) {
    $ret = "";
    while ($len > 0 && !feof($this->ms)) {
        $red = fread($this->stream, $len);
        $ret .= $red;
        $len -= strlen($red);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Whether the transfer succeeds or not, there are still some potentially time consuming things to do so I've set ignore_user_abort(true) and a connection close header is posted right after the upload is complete.

What I'm worried about is that if the client drops out in the middle of upload, that while loop there might block any further execution as its waiting for bytes that will never come.

I'm hoping that feof over there will get me out of the loop if that should happen but I haven't been able to slow down the upload to localhost enough to have much confidence in my testing so I figured I'd just ask.

Will feof return true if the connection has been aborted mid stream?

Comment: Why don't you simply test it?

Comment: @arkascha I've tried, I havent been able to cut the connection before the whole upload is complete since its nearly instantaneous in localhost

Comment: Why don’t you simulate slow connection? Read stream in small chunks, sleep (for 100ms for instance) after each read.

Comment: You can use a script creating an endless input stream instead of sending a file. That should give you enough time.

Comment: @emix I tried that too but whether I read it or not, the data is already in the stream and has its natural eof

Answer (score 0):

`stream_get_line` handles disconnections